# Shiny/ShinyJS disable download Button

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

This is a simple example of an issue I am having with ShinyJS (I think).  In the initial state, I want the downloadButton to be disabled.  When the user clicks on the actionButton, I want to have the downloadButton enabled.  This should be straightforward, but I can't get this to work.  Any suggestions? Thanks

My Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  actionButton("tButton",label="Toggle Download Button"),
 downloadButton("singlePDF", label="Output Profile to PDF"),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("ui"))
  )

server <- function(session,input, output) { 
  #disabling the singlePDF button (the download PDF function)
  # Want the initial state of this button to be disabled
  shinyjs::disable(id="singlePDF")  
  observeEvent(input$tButton,{
      shinyjs::enable(id="singlePDF")  #want the button to enable
      output$ui <- renderUI(outputList)
      lnout <- tags$h2("Button pressed")
      outputList <- list(lnout)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I think you need to add `useShinyjs()` in your UI. Adding this piece will make it work. Please read `help(useShinyjs)` for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  The code now works.  Cheers AB

Comment: Glad I could help.